# Babel javascript export uncaught referenceerror for export statements

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am developing a javascript code that transpiling with Babel.

Math module:

```
export const factorial = (n) =>{
    if (n < 2) { return 1; }

    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

babel.config.json:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist/js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2"
  }
```

So I am runnign the code "`npm run build`" and transpiling main.js in /dist/js folder like this:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.factorial = void 0;
var factorial = function factorial(n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return 1;
  }
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
};
exports.factorial = factorial;
```

But when I add this jaacript file in my html,

```
<body>
    Hello Javascript
    <script src="dist/js/math.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser gives error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Comment: I added targets options in this documnet but did not work.

Comment: Give a  chance to "targets": {
    "esmodules": true
  }      and add  type="module" to your script tag  (remember to not exec the code in localhost too)

Comment: @Nick I added but does not work `{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env", 
            { 
                "targets":{
                    "esmodules": true
                }
            }
        ]
    ] 
    
}`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Babel produces CommonJS module code. Usually, people use a bundler of some kind (Webpack, Vite, Rollup, Rome, Parcel, ...), which consumes the CommonJS module code and builds browser bundles.

If you don't want to use a bundler, you have at least three options:

1. You can not use Babel at all, you don't need it for the code you've shown.
2. You can use JavaScript standard modules ("ESM" for "ECMAScript Module") by adding the `modules: false` option to the `env` plugin's config.
3. You can use a [module transform plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-umd) to produce an AMD or UMD build instead for use in browsers if you're not using a bundler.

### Not using Babel

One option is to just not use Babel at all. The code you've shown will work in any non-obsolete browser, as long as you have `type="module"` on your `script` tag (although that particular module you probably wouldn't have a `script` tag for at all; instead, you'd `import` it from some other module loaded via a `type="module"` script tag).

For instance, if you had:

```html
<script type="module" src="./index.js">
```

and `index.js` had:

```js
import { factorial } from "./math.js";
```

...the code will work just fine.

But perhaps you plan to use newer features that are still working their way through the proposals process.

### Using ESM

To use ESM, just specify `modules: false` for the `env` plugin:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}]
    ]
}
```

Now the output will use the same ESM module syntax you're using in your source code, which you can use in a `script type="module"` script tag (although, again, most likely you wouldn't use a `script` tag with this particular module, but instead with a module *using* this module):

```js
export var factorial = function factorial(n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return 1;
  }
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
};
```

(See my comment about `targets` at the end of the answer, it's odd to see ESM and ES5 at the same time. :-) )

### Using a module transform plugin

Alternatively, if you don't want to use native modules, you can use a module transform plugin, such as the UMD plugin. First, install it:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd
```

Then configure it in your `babel.config.json`:

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd"]
}
```

When you do that, the resulting code works in a variety of environments (including as a non-module script file in a browser) by detecting the environment and defining things appropriately. It seems a bit verbose, but the overhead doesn't grow as your code grows:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["exports"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
    factory(exports);
  } else {
    var mod = {
      exports: {}
    };
    factory(mod.exports);
    global.index = mod.exports;
  }
})(typeof globalThis !== "undefined" ? globalThis : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : this, function (_exports) {
  "use strict";

  Object.defineProperty(_exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });
  _exports.factorial = void 0;
  var factorial = function factorial(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
      return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  };
  _exports.factorial = factorial;
});
```

---

Side note: You'll want to specify [`targets`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#targets) as well, otherwise Babel transpfiles your code all the way down to ES5 (although with `modules: false` it's ES5 plus ESM, which is an odd mix), but there are no non-obsolete environments that don't support something more modern than that.

Comment: You said "people use a bundler of some kind", is "webpack" a bundler for this opinion?

Comment: @barteloma - Yes, Webpack is a bundler. There are **lots** of them though -- Webpack, Vite, Rollup, Rome, Parcel, ...

Comment: when I use a module transform plugin, I can not access the "factorial" function from html file.